# Assigning webhooks to Firebase Messaging "subscribe to topic" event

Tags: firebase-cloud-messaging, webhooks

In my current project I am using the [Kreait](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php) Firebase PHP SDK to send out push notifications to Android & iOS devices that have subscribed to notifications on named topics.  No issues thus far.  However, rather than have fixed topic names I would now like to generate topic names based on the current "condition" of the connecting device.  The condition could, for example, be a geographic location.

This is not too difficult either and I have modified my app to handle this.  However, in order to put the ability to have such autogenerated topics to use I need to know the topic names on my server so I can send out targeted messages via Kreait.  I find Google's Firebase documentation a bit dense at times and have not been able to establish whether it is possible to assign webhooks that get called by Firebase whenever a `SubscribeToTopic`, `UnsubscribeFromTopic` event occurs.

A simple question - does FCM even offer anything like this capability?  If so, any pointers to the relevant documentation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no public API to get a list of topic names from Firebase, nor is there a way to hook into the subscription mechanism.

Your best bet is to simply make two calls when a user subscribes to a topic: one to Firebase, and one to your own backend API that keeps a list of active topics/conditions.